# JMathPlot what is the Maven dependency code please

Tags: java, maven, jmathplot

Does anyone know the Maven dependency code for JMathPlot for eclipse

```
 <dependency>
      <groupId>jmathplot</groupId>
      <artifactId>jmathplot</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
      <scope>system</scope>
      <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/jmathplot.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
```

Error is it can't find jmathplot/jmathplot/1.0

EDIT1:

OK I put the jar file in folder

C:/Users/MyName/Eclipse/Workspace1/MyProjectName/

Next to src, target,assembly folders

I changed dependency to:

```
 <dependency>
          <groupId>jmathplot</groupId>
          <artifactId>jmathplot</artifactId>
          <version>1.0</version>
          <scope>system</scope>
          <systemPath>${project.basedir}/jmathplot.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
```

And I get the error:

com.tradable.terminal!.plugin.storage.Tr!PluginPackageException: PluginId: com.NoviumResearch.ValueAtRisk, The resource lib/jmathplot.jar does not exist

It seems to be trying to look in "lib" not sure why

Answer (score 1):

With your Maven snippet you're telling Maven to get the jar from this path: {project folder}/lib/jmathplot.jar

You can solve the issue creating a lib folder in the Eclipse project and then copy there the jmathplot jar.

You can download the jar from here: http://jmathplot.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jmathplot/dist/jmathplot.jar

Comment: OH I see - I thought point of Maven was to NOT have to supply the jar

Comment: Yes in normal case, in this case the library author have not published the library in maven so you've to retrieve it manually.

Comment: My project has src, target and assembly folders do I create "lib" next to these or within one?

Comment: Right click "create folder" a simple one.

Comment: YEs BUT where in the structure?

Comment: In the root. Ok next (sibling) others folders src and target.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40128/discussion-between-fedy2-and-maninmoon)